# How to make button clicked as default from Array

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I have an array like below where I stored my languages and their boolean values. I want to make button auto clicked(Active) for each true language in the array. Of course, after language changed(which means when the user clicks another button), that bool of current language should be true. I created my array in .ts and buttons in HTML but couldn't connect them together. Here what I tried below

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div *ngFor="lang of languages" class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons" id="left">
        <h4>Language</h4>
        <button style="margin-left:10px;" type="button" class="btn btn-light">{{lang.value}}</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

languages: Language[] = [ {value: 'english',bool:true}, {value: 'dutch',bool:false} ];
```

Answer (score 1):

Buttons aren't stateful, the `active`, `focus`, `hover` pseudoclasses are just, in facts, pseudoclasses that get applied when those user events happen.

You can programmatically simulate those events, but it's not much reliable. If you set the `active` or `focus`ed pseudostate to a button and the user clicks anywhere else, the pseudostate will be removed.

You need to use some stateful element and, if you want, style it as buttons. For example a checbox would be perfect for your case:

```css
input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked), 
input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999%;
}

input[type="checkbox"] + label {
  border: solid 1px gray;
  background-color: lightgray;
  color: gray;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  user-select: none;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
  background-color: royalblue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="cb" name="cb">
<label for="cb">Click me</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all change `*ngFor="lang of languages"` to `*ngFor="let lang of languages"` then make an activate-method in your component.ts and bind it to the on click event `(click)="activate(lang)"`. See below:

```js
 languages: Language[] = [
    {value: 'english',bool:true},
    {value: 'dutch',bool:false}
  ];
  
  
  activate(lang): void {
    this.languages.forEach(lang => lang.bool = false);
    lang.bool = true;
  }
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div *ngFor="let lang of languages" class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons" id="left">
        <h4>Language</h4>                                   
        <button style="margin-left:10px;" type="button" class="btn btn-light" (click)="activate(lang)">{{lang.value}}, active: {{lang.bool | json }}</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```